# Is a Hash Function really useful in a Smart Contract Election?

Tags: blockchain, security, hash

Noob here. Was reading this: https://karl.tech/learning-solidity-part-2-voting/

**From my basic understanding, a hash function:**

- Receives an input (like `x`) and spits some result (like `y`)
- `y` is calculated upon the contents of `x` (so the same `x` will always
  hash to the same `y`)
- It's non reversible (if you have `y`, you cannot get `x`)

Sounds good, but think about the following scenario.

**There's an election on an Ethereum Smart Contract with 3 Candidates:**

1. `C1`
2. `C2`
3. `C3`

**Same logic:**

- Voter can't know who other Voters voted for. Results must only be
  revealed after the election is over.
- To vote, each voter must distribute their hash.
- Once all votes are submitted/election period is over, all voters
  distribute their actual vote.
- Then you can verify that the Distributed Vote hashes to the
  previously Distributed Hash, and the vote can be counted. Sounds
  good.

**But in a Smart Contract Election scenario:**

- All voters know the `name/id/label` of the 3 candidates.
- All voters have access to the Smart Contract's code and can see which
  hash function was used.

**Couldn't the voters just:**

1. Run the hash function for each candidate `name/id/label` by
   themselves
2. Write down the resulting hash for each candidate (it would be the
   same for each candidate every time, right?)
3. Go see which hashes are distributed in the Blockchain and reverse
   engineer who each person voted for?

*I don't really know that much, so this might be a stupid question.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this part:

> In this implementation, a vote for choice1 will take the form:
> `1-my_secret_password` and a vote for choice2 will take the form:
> `2-my_other_secret_password`
>
> Notice that the 1 and 2 are the actual
> votes. The passwords are included to make sure votes remain secret
> until the reveal period. Each vote is required to use a unique
> password. If two votes were to use the same password, then the vote
> commits will be the same. If the vote commits are the same, then only
> one vote will be counted!

This is exactly to prevent what you are describing. You basically create a random number locally and this will be included in the hash computation. No one else knows this number, so no one can reverse engineer it.

Comment: I read again and now I understand it better: the hash won't be "reverse-engineerable" because an unknown password was included. But do you really need a unique password for each vote? "1-password123" and "2-password123" will still hash to different things. Or do you mean you will only need unique passwords if you are voting for the same candidate multiple times?

Comment: @antoniopgs After the election you reveal your password(s), so any following elections should use completely different passwords. Before you reveal any password, you could in theory use similar ones. Just know that once you reveal one password, all other votes with similar passwords could be guessed.